# microsoft graph API /calendars id is not unique

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

When requesting calendars, the ID returned from the calendar sometimes changes. 
We saw that the name of calendar differs sometimes (*agenda* or *Calendar*) - this is also reflected in the `changeKey` field, but would that mean that the calendar ID also changes?

It does not happen to all of our clients, just a few. What can cause this? What are we missing?
We already use the **Immutable Id** headers, but these don't apply to the calendars according to the docs.

```
{
        "id": "AAMkADgyMzdkNzAyLTVhZGEtNDg1Yi***AAAAEGAAAqQIxwV34sQLN18DH-lwsGAAAAAYeRAAA=",
        "name": "Agenda",
        "color": "auto",
        "changeKey": "qr2mXiE5k0+ASL9waSq4XAADFAI=",
        "canShare": true,
        "canViewPrivateItems": true,
        "canEdit": true,
        "owner": {
            "name": "***",
            "address": "***@***.com"
        }
    },
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain how you requested **ImmutableId**? This should be working now for events as well.

Comment: ImmutableId was passed in the headers of the request. My question is about _calendars_, not events;

``` 'Prefer' => 'IdType="ImmutableId"'```

Comment: **ImmutableId** should be returned for calendars as well, this is just another 'folder' in the mailbox. Just tried that and getting expected behavior. This is how it should look like: `Prefer:IdType=ImmutableId`

Comment: We already pass this header when requesting calendars but unfortunately it still happens that a calendar gets another ID. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: This is really strange in case **ImmutableId** is used. How often that happen? Moving folder to another mailbox or to archive could cause this, however, this isn't scenario you are facing. Any chance next time this happens you can paste previous and current (changed) Id? Please note, Id's arent containing any PII data in it. Just some bytes (and guid in case of EntryId).

Comment: Hi @IvanFranjic The id's we're currently seeing are these:

original ID: 

`AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AKkCMcFd_LECzdfAx-5cLBgABIY_KcAAA` (Agenda)
`AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AKkCMcFd_LECzdfAx-5cLBgABLe4oVAAA` (Calendar)


New iD:
`AAMkADgyMzdkNzAyLTVhZGEtNDg1Yi04ODZhLTczMTRiMGYyMzdkMgBGAAAAAACyNgCTvd0lSK6vQGLKRsMTBwAqQIxwV34sQLN18DH-lwsGAAAAAAEGAAAqQIxwV34sQLN18DH-lwsGAAAAAYeRAAA=` (Agenda)

Comment: First two (original ID) are **ImmutableId**'s, while new id is **EntryId**. If you've gotten that in your responses, this looks like one request goes out asking for **ImmutableId** and the other goes without that and **EntryId** is returned by default.

Comment: Sorry, I made a booboo, the new (immutable) id is `AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AKkCMcFd_LECzdfAx-5cLBgABLe6Y6gAA` (Agenda)

While I don't understand these differ from the originals

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, calendars are actually folders under the covers and therefore are not affected by the ImmutableId prefer header.  The reason for this is that folder ids are *supposed* to stay the same within a given mailbox regardless of where they are moved.  As such, a calendar only has one id (PR_ENTRYID) and no immutableId (PR_IMMUTABLE_ENTRYID).

That doesn't of course explain what is happening here.  I am curious if it is possible that the calendar folder is getting *recreated* somehow which would explain why the calendar id would be changing.  Can you look at the creation time of the folder to see if it is more recent than you expect it to be?

Comment: We changed the uuid used for now, but we can only see that the calendar was first added in april 2019 and that recently (a few weeks ago) the ID that the /me/calendars call returned was different.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with calendar folder immutable ids where they do change that is being investigated by our engineering team. Apologies for the inconvenience here.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for letting us know. Could you update this stack overflow issue when it's fixed?

Comment: We just recently saw the same issue happening on the calendar of one of our clients

Comment: following up internally and will get back to you.

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT Is there any news on this issue?

Comment: This is still not solved, could you look into my post, I have details for when it happened: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044009/calendar-id-randomly-changed @JeremyThakeMSFT